# finding maximum value form csv column

Tags: python, csv

```
dataset=[]
f= open('auto-mpg-data.csv')
csv_f=csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    dataset.append(row)

#reading column
mpg=[]
for row in dataset:
    mpg.append(row[0])
print(mpg)

print(max(mpg))
```

this is the [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcGgV.png). When I try to find the maximum value from this list it show 9 instead of 46.6. How can I get this value?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the items of the list `mpg` are strings, so the result is true as '9' is greater than '46.6' when comparing strings.  You should convert the items in the list `mpg` to float numbers first:

```
mpg = [float(row[0]) for row in dataset]
```